# while loop condtion, difference between not equal and greater than

Tags: java

I'm doing a problem checking whether an integer is a palindrome. The logic is I convert it to string and then set the index of the first and the last. I loop through each first and last index and the values should match if they are palindrome. in the loop I increase the first index by one, I decrease the last index by one. So eventually they will meet in the half. The loop condition I originally had was if the indexes of both are not the same. but this gives me String index out of bounds exception. But then when I changed it to loop through as long as start is smaller than the end, it works.

```
public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {

        if(x < 0) {
            return false;
        }       
        String val = String.valueOf(x);

        int end = val.length()-1;
        int start = 0;
        while(start != end) {
            if(val.charAt(start) != val.charAt(end)) {
                return false;
            }
            start++;
            end--;
        }

        return true;
    }
    }
```

it works when I do

```
 if(str.charAt(start++) < str.charAt(end--)) return false;
```

Comment: You have written the wrong condition in question at the end.

For odd numbers of a digit in number your condition will work but for even numbers of a digit in number if you will trace down then start and end will never be equal, both will just cross each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have problem if the length is even number. For example if length is 4, you will have this run:

```
START | END
0     3
1     2
2     1
3     0
4     -1 <--- error
```

as during whole time the condition of not-equality is true.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the number of digit in the number :

for example, for `1221`, `start` and `end` will never meet in the middle :

- iteration 1 : start = 0, end = 3
- iteration 2 : start = 1, end = 2
- iteration 3 : start = 2, end = 1
  ...

The fact that "it works" when you do :

```
 if(str.charAt(start++) < str.charAt(end--)) return false;
```

is by chance.

You should just change the `while` condition to :

```
while(start < end) {
```